# Parse CSV using new line as seperator

Tags: php, arrays, excel, parsing, csv

I have the following in a CSV file exported from Excel

```
Lol,Man,11
Hello,World,11
My,Name,12
Is,Epic,11
```

How would I parse this using PHP to an array?

Currently I am using

```
$line = file_get_contents("Day1.CSV");

$parsed = str_getcsv(
    $line, # Input line
    ',',   # Delimiter
    '"',   # Enclosure
    '//'   # Escape char
);
```

But that's not working.

Comment: It had new lines separating. The below code does the job.

Comment: i had assumed you had left that part out, being obvious. my mistake

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [fgetcsv](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fgetcsv.php) (example from the manual page)

```
if (($handle = fopen("Day1.CSV", "r")) !== FALSE) 
{
    while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ",", "//")) !== FALSE) 
    {
        // do something with the data here
        echo $data[0] . " - ". $data[1] . " - ". $data[2] . "</br>" ;
    }
    fclose($handle);
}
```

Alternatively in your implementation, you can do this:

```
$contents = file_get_contents("Day1.CSV");

$data = str_getcsv("\n");

foreach ($data as $row)
{
    $output = str_getcsv($row, ',', '"', '//');

    // do something with the data here
    echo $output[0] . " - " $output[1] . " - " $output[2] . "\n";
}
```

HTH

Comment: Great. Few mistakes that cause PHP errors:
Fixed here: http://pastebin.com/4LRG14n2

Thanks!

Comment: Thanks for the pointer. Edited the above to reflect those corrections.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$str="Lol,Man,11";

$out=str_getcsv($str,",",'','');

print_r($out); //Array ( [0] => Lol [1] => Man [2] => 11 )
```

OR

```
$out=explode(",",$str);
```